# Cannot get Bootstrap 4 custom.css

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

Here is my _custom.scss:

```
// Bootstrap overrides
//
// Copy variables from `_variables.scss` to this file to override default values
// without modifying source files.
//$body-bg:    $gray-dark;
//$body-color: $gray-light;
$blue:   #363636;
$component-active-bg: #484545;
$dropdown-bg: $brand-primary;
$dropdown-link-color: #c3c3c3;
$dropdown-link-hover-color:  darken(#c3c3c3, 5%);
```

and bootstrap.scss:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "_custom";
```

I am compiling it with the provided Gruntfile.js.
The resultant css file has no effect. Everything looks just like with the original css.
How can I test whether I am getting compilation process actually working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the format of boostrap.scss I think you should have:

```
@import "custom";
```

Next, when you make your changes in _custom.scss, leave off the "!default" tag. For example:

```
// _variables.css
$blue:   #0275d8 !default;
/// _custom.css
$blue:   #002b5b;
```